# Facebook SDK Manage pages error: The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting this weird Facebook PHP SDK error just with some of the users of my app.

This is the array of permissions I am requiring to the users:

```
['email', 'publish_stream', 'manage_pages', 'read_insights', 'status_update']
```

My app publish content on the Facebook pages of my users, using an extended access token for different weeks.

Since I've updated to the Facebook SDK v4 few weeks back, some of the users are getting this error:

```
"The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action."
```

Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use publish_actions instead of publish_stream. publish_stream have been deprecated for years

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and I will let you know if it has worked.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Now though, when you ask the publish_action permission, Facebook will prompt the user an additional step in permission granting process (when the user signup for the first time). Here you can find more details why http://globalspin.com/2013/06/publish_stream-vs-publish_actions/

Comment: You should never ask for publish_actions when a user signs up for the first time. You should ask for it when you need it.